# Name of the JSON response in a ForEach in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am working on a small projet with a specific JSON API

I got  this JSON from response of the API.

```
{
    "3": {
        "email": "email@domain.com",
        "ext": "100",
        "location": "remote",
        "name": "Test Extension",
        "protocol": "sip",
        "status": "enabled",
    },
    "66": {
        "email": "support@domain.com",
        "ext": "101",
        "location": "remote",
        "name": "Test2",
        "protocol": "sip",
        "status": "enabled",
    }
}
```

I want to get result like that:

```
Extension: 100
Nom: Test Extension
ID: 3
Status: enabled

Extension: 101
Nom: Test2
ID:66
Status: enabled
```

I cannot find the way to get the ID for each of the array...

My code is :

```
$json = file_get_contents($list);
$queries = json_decode($json);




foreach($queries as $query){
  echo "<br>Extension: ";
  echo $query->ext;
  echo "<br>Nom: ";
  echo $query->name;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "ID:";
  echo $id;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "    Status:  ";
  echo $query->status;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `foreach` itself you can get index

```
foreach($queries as $id => $query){
  echo "<br>Extension: ";
  echo $query->ext;
  echo "<br>Nom: ";
  echo $query->name;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "ID:";
  echo $id;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "    Status:  ";
  echo $query->status;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Pretty sure I try something similar before and couldn't make it work, but its definitely work.